# How to output Chinese in HTML file

Tags: php, encoding

I have a form and insert some chinese words in database and it's ok. Table charset is UTF8. Problem appears when I select this data and send it via mail as HTML attachment.
Then, Chinese doesn't display properly. How to fix charset before send data via mail? Should I use some headers and will it work?

My code looks like that:

```html
//$attachedBodyContent is data from database that contains some chinese words
Mail::send(
            "emails.applicationTemplate",
            $data,
            function($message) use ($data, $template, $subject, $attachedBodyContent) {
                $message->to($data['email'], $data['name'])
                    ->from($template['from'],$template['from_name'])
                    ->subject($subject)
                    ->attachData($attachedBodyContent,'YourApplicationData.html');
              
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you generate .html attach file you should include in your `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

In this case you can use this code for merge your content with `<head>`

```
<?php
    $header = '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>';
    $footer = '</body>
    </html>';
    $allContent = $header.$attachedBodyContent.$footer;
?>
```

Comment: How to put it in html, in my html file I don't even have <head> tag, I select from database user data and I have email template and I parse user data into template.  $attachedBodyContent = strtr($templateApplicationData['body'], $attachedData);  This  $attachedBodyContent is content of my html file. How to add <head> tag with meta ?

Comment: Thank you, I have just fond another way with :  $attachedBodyContent = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head><body>';
        $attachedBodyContent .= strtr($templateApplicationData['body'], $attachedData);
        $attachedBodyContent .= '</body></html>';

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

This should do it, for further information check the link.

http://www.inventpartners.com/chinese-chars